# loop not breaking in pinescript, tradingview. Need it to stop at first true

Tags: loops, for-loop, pine-script, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

i have a if statement and it makes a label every time the condition is true. I would like it to stop when first true and break.

below is my code

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
entry=92.40
current_price=close
price_higher=entry+0.40


CrossedUp = current_price <= price_higher
//CrossedDown = current_price < price_lower   
if CrossedUp
      
    LongBE = label.new(
      x=bar_index, 
      y=na, 
      text="BE Long",
      xloc=xloc.bar_index,
      yloc=yloc.abovebar, 
      color=color.orange, 
      textcolor=color.white, 
      style=label.style_label_down, 
      size=size.tiny)
```

so it is showing a label each time the condition is true, however i just want it to show once?

Comment: Where is the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to show it once, use a `var` flag to see if the condition has occured before.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
entry=92.40
current_price=close
price_higher=entry+0.40
var is_label_created = false

CrossedUp = current_price <= price_higher
//CrossedDown = current_price < price_lower   
if CrossedUp and not is_label_created
      
    LongBE = label.new(
      x=bar_index, 
      y=na, 
      text="BE Long",
      xloc=xloc.bar_index,
      yloc=yloc.abovebar, 
      color=color.orange, 
      textcolor=color.white, 
      style=label.style_label_down, 
      size=size.tiny)
    
    is_label_created := true
```

Comment: it shows no labels instead of many?

Comment: CrossedUp = current_price <= price_higher should be:
CrossedUp = current_price > price_higher

Comment: It will show one label only when your condition is `true` for the very first time. And the label will stay there forever. If you want to move it when some other condition occurs, you can use `label.set_x()` function.

Comment: I added a date function to test your code and it worked as you said. However I think I under estimated my problem. I have asked a newer question here o. Stack overflow. Can you kindly have a look? Many thanks